# How can I stop mac connecting to HDMI audio device

Tags: audio, google-chrome, hdmi

I have this issue where, for some reason, Chrome always defaults to hdmi audio when my display is plugged in. I've had to install a plugin just to have the option to change it (since chrome weirdly doesn't provide this functionality), and I'm SOOO sick of having to switch the audio device every time I open a new tab.

Is there any reliable way I can prevent my mac from EVER being able to use HDMI for audio?

Comment: What strikes me as most odd is that only one app does this. Without 3rd party intercept, the Mac can only output to one global destination from all internal sources. This is most eminently fixable, but requires 3rd party support.

Comment: Have you tried changing the global audio output in system preferences? I believe it remembers your last choice, but not sure.

Comment: @JBallin Yeah I've tried everything I could think of in sys preferences and audio midi setup. Seems like it's more of an issue with Chrome, but the annoyance of it all just makes me wish I could disable hdmi audio from ever being an option.